# Getting nested data from two tables mysql Laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have three tables

1. plans columns->id,name
   2.features columns->id,name
   3.feature_in_plans columns->plan_id,feature_id

and I want to get the features of each plan like below

[image]

how to write in eloquent query?

Comment: Show your defined relationships in your models

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Plan::with('features')->get();
```

I assume you've defined `features` relationship in `Plan` model. If not, do it:

```
public function features()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Feature::class);
}
```

Comment: I am just a beginner and how to set relationship in these three tables?

Comment: @YanMyoAung you need to define just one relationship to make the query work. I've added it to my answer.

Comment: I just named feature_in_plans and didn't name feature_plan and SQL ERROR base table not found showing.How can I get it manually?

Comment: @YanMyoAung rename the table to `feature_plan` (since it's pivot table) to make the relationship work. Read more about naming conventions here https://github.com/alexeymezenin/laravel-best-practices#follow-laravel-naming-conventions

Comment: thank anyway @Alex I want to know can I get these things by manual sql query without using relationship?

Comment: @YanMyoAung you can, but why you want to do that using SQL? Use Eloquent, it'll allow you to build maintainable applications.

Comment: Yes I am going to use Eloquent but I just want to learn new things about manual query can u recommend me some links?

Comment: You can always read Laravel docs, there are a lot of Query Builder and raw SQL examples there. I don't use raw queries, so I won't be able to recommend you any good tutorial.

Comment: I got my right answer. I set the pivot table name in relationship like this 
    public function features()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Feature::class,'feature_in_plans');
    }

Comment: @YanMyoAung this will work for sure, but I really recommend you to follow Laravel naming conventions.

Comment: Yes I will obey next times but I cant change becz my app is in production lvl and db design is not created by me.